# Bash script or makefile to compile an application then perform permission elevated operations

Tags: bash, make

I have a golang-based application and associated systemd files in a project. I'm working on a bash script (`install.sh`) (or a Makefile if that is a better option) that helps to automate the following (basically in this order), but am running into permissions problems:

Goals:

- Automate building the application binary as a non-root user
- Copy the systemd file to the correct path (requires elevated permissions)
- Stop/start the service to load the updated application (requires elevated permissions).

Ideal steps in the bash script:

- As a non-sudo/non-elevated user, remove the existing binary and rebuild it `go build -o binary_name .`. This step should be run as my user (compiling code as sudo isn't a great idea.)
- Elevate permissions
- Remove the existing `/etc/systemd/system/binary_name.service` file.
- Copy the `binary_name.service` file to  `/etc/systemd/system/binary_name.service` in case it was updated.
- Stop and restart the `binary_name` service.

Problems I'm running into:
 - If I execute `sudo install.sh`, we run into the "don't compile as sudo/root" issue. Also, the `go` package isn't found due to different environment settings.
 - If I executed `install.sh` without sudo, permission problems crop up when the script attempts to remove/copy the service files.

Following is an abbreviated version of the current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  (das_application) 
    cd /usr/local/apps/das_application/

    # rebuild das_application binary
    echo "Removing old das_application binary"
    rm das_application
    echo "Building updated das_application binary"
    go build -o das_application .
    echo "Done building das_application binary"

    echo "Stopping das_application service"
    sudo systemctl stop das_application

    echo "Copying das_application.service to /etc/systemd/system"
    rm /etc/systemd/system/das_application.service
    cp ./conf/das_application.service /etc/systemd/system/das_application.service

    systemctl daemon-reload

    echo "Starting das_application service"
    systemctl start das_application.service

    exit 1
    ;;
  (*)
    echo "Use as ./install.sh das_application"
    exit 2
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question.  One of the possible solutions would be checking if
script is being run with `sudo`, exiting if it's not and temporarily
dropping privileges to run commands that should be run as a regular
user.  Something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ -z "$SUDO_USER" ]
then
    printf "Not running with sudo. Exiting\n"
    exit 1
fi

touch SUDO-FILE

# drop privileges temporarily
su "$SUDO_USER" -c 'touch REGULAR-FILE'
```

After running that you can see 2 files - `SUDO-FILE` owned by root and
its primary group and `REGULAR-FILE` file owned by the regular user
and its primary group:

```
$ ls -Alhtr SUDO-FILE REGULAR-FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Dec  5 21:06 SUDO-FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja   users 0 Dec  5 21:06 REGULAR-FILE
```

Tested on Slackware Linux and FreeBSD. You can also use `su -l` that will source your regular user's shell login script such as `~/.profile`.

I'm not sure what drawbacks and possible gotchas this solution has
though so make sure you ran a couple of tests before using it in the
production.

Answer (score 0):

I would split your script into two:

- One to build, which doesn't require to be run as root. (your current `install.sh` that would be renamed `build.sh`)
- One to install, which requires to be run as root. (the real `deploy.sh`).

And, why not a 3rd script that would be called `install.sh` and would do:

1. call `build.sh` regulary.
2. call `sudo deploy.sh`

Comment: It's not a good idea to create a 3rd script that would request `sudo` password in the middle of its execution - it's usually not expected by users, if password is not entered with the time specified it will timeout and the script will fail.